# I want to import an old Vuforia app

Tags: android, import, vuforia

I just got started developing android apps. I have this app on github that I really would like to run on my computer, but I'm failing. The app is about(I believe) navigating through ARview using Vuforia to show directions on ARview. 
I downloaded as a ZIP and extracted, and imported the folder in 
AndroidStudio. It seems to me that AndroidStudio is not accepting this as an android project. Is there anyway that I can run this?

This is the page that I downloaded from:
https://github.com/lukaspili-brookes/AR-Navigation-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use "File/New/Import Project...".  I just tried it here with that project and it worked...though sounds like you got that part working?  I do see issue though where you don't get option to run....I think problem is that top level `build.gradle` file is empty.

Comment: If you don't mind could you please tell me which OS you are running on and the version of android studio?

Comment: Now I see that build.gradle is empty.. so did you then add anything to top level build.gradle?

Comment: @Hoon what I'd suggest is creating new android project and you should then be able to see what top level build.gradle contains.